# Pie Chart Doesn't Close

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

```
\begin{document}
\begin {tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]

   \pie [sum=100]{46.5/, 31.6/, 8.2/, 13.7/}

   \pie [text=legend,pos ={7.9,0}]{46.8/Limerock, 31.9/Sand,7.5/Water,13.8/Cement}

\end {tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need help closing the pie charts...Every time I recompile there is a small fraction that isn't closed. Any help?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example, i.e. a compilable document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Otherwise you may have to wait very long until you find out who stole the piece of your pie ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the package was outdated.  An update solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot reproduce with latest [`pgf-pie.sty` from CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin {tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
  \pie[sum=100]{46.5/, 31.6/, 8.2/, 13.7/}
  \pie[text=legend,pos={7.9,0}]{46.8/Limerock, 31.9/Sand,7.5/Water,13.8/Cement}
\end {tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you to mention that [pgf-pie.sty](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-pie?lang=en) is *not* included in tex-live? (That is, if @Griff uses tex-live, and uses an outdated version, this might be the reason for the missing piece.)

Comment: Thank you. Also, how exactly do I caption each graph? I want to label the left one "Mix A1" and the right one "Mix A2." I want the captions to be above.

Comment: @Griff [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @Griff  `\node at (0,3.5) {Mix A1};
  \node at (7.9,3.5) {Mix A2};`